# Will there be any problems when I mix these memory modules?

Tags: memory

2gb + 2gb DDR2 PC2-6400 CL5 Micron RAM sticks with a 2gb DDR2 PC2-6400 CL5 Apacer stick?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of compatibility, the speed and CAS timings are all the same, so they should get along with each other quite happily.

One note is that you will not see the maximum performance as you are not installing the memory in pairs.  I see that you are installing just 3 sticks, 3x2GB compared to 2x2GB and 2x1GB for example which would run quicker.  See [**here**](http://www.crucial.com/kb/answer.aspx?qid=4079&click=true) for more information.  Just being picky to be honest, what you have should still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are both standards-based (which being DDR2 PC2-6400, they should be), there won't be any issues.

Good luck!